# how to call a php function from my html form?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a template for a website, and I want to  customize the message sender there. I saw [this form](http://youhack.me/2010/07/22/create-a-fancy-contact-form-with-css-3-and-jquery/) to help out with the implementation of it.

the php file looks like this:

```
<?php
echo 'testing php'; 
$name = $_POST['name']; // contain name of person
$email = $_POST['email']; // Email address of sender 
$web = $_POST['web']; // Your website URL
$body = $_POST['text']; // Your message 
$receiver = "myEmail@hotmail.com" ; // hardcorde your email address here - This is the email address that all your feedbacks will be sent to 

$body = "Name:{$name}\n\nWebsite :{$web}\n\nComments:{$body}";
$send = mail($receiver, 'Contact Form Submission', $body, $email);
if ($send) {
    echo 'true'; //if everything is ok,always return true , else ajax submission won't work
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

I've managed to call the php file like this:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="ajaxSubmit.php" > 
                <fieldset> 
                <label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Name" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Name' ) this.value=''"></label>
                  <label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Email" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Email'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Email' ) this.value=''"></label> 
                <label><input type="text" id="web" name="web" value="Phone" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Phone'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Phone' ) this.value=''"></label>
                  <label><textarea id="text" name="text" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value=''}">Message</textarea></label> 
                <input type="reset" /> 
                <input type="submit" /> 
                </fieldset> 
                </form>
```

but when I run this I get teh following **ERROR**

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid. in C:\wamp\www\forSale\dataTable\ajaxSubmit.php on line 17
```

but then I check the vallues of the variables, they are correct. what does that mean?

Comment: "always hits failure" - what kind of failure? have you turned on php error reporting?

Comment: The ajax call fires with this code? Your onclick states sendemailFunction() but the function defined is sendEmail(). I assume this doesn't reflect your actual code.

Comment: Are you able to send emails from php, without ajax?

Comment: at MAtt K, I'm kinda new to php, so I dunno how to debug php code. I degun the javascript through firebug and it goes into the sendEmail(); but goes through it. I think it might not even be hitting the php code, how can I check that?

Comment: You didn't specify how the data is being sent via AJAX. iirc, this means that AJAX defaults to $_GET. This is easy enough to test...

Comment: @Zombaya, idk, how do I test that?

Comment: make a test.php and run something like `$send = mail('mypersonalemail@provider.com','Test','testbody','sender@example.com');`and show an output based on `$send`

Comment: so I'll create a php dile, and just put $send = mail('mypersonalemail@provider.com','Test','testbody','sender@example.com'); in it and that's it? how do I show the output? thourgh the same php file? I'm sorry I'm terrible new at this, is tehre a page you know that has a very simple example on how to call a php function from clicking on an html button?

Comment: After that first line of `$send = ...` you could put `if ($send) {
    echo 'I was able to send an email'; 
}
else {
    echo 'I could not send an email';
}`
Then you would just have to browse to that php-page like a normal html-page.  If it is in your document-root, you should be able to go to http://localhost/test.php

Comment: there, added a echo and added what I get if I go into the php file through localhost/ajaxSubmit.php , but I try going through the html, nothing happens. I think the php code is not being hit. that ajax call is wrong. how would you call taht function from html?

Comment: Well, you can check that by going to firebug to the netpanel (which is disabled by default, so you should enable it if it's still disabled) and then you have to check if you make an extra request to the webserver when you submit your form.  If you make a request, your php-code will run.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10720/discussion-between-myy-and-zombaya)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the chat, you should try by starting from the ground up by first submitting the form normally, then improve it by validating it with javascript and after that try to submit it with ajax.

If you modify the form back to basics you get:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="ajaxSubmit.php" >
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Name" 
                    onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Name'" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Name' ) this.value=''" />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  value="Email" 
                    onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Email'"
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Email' ) this.value=''" />
        <input type="text" id="web" name="web"  value="Phone" 
                    onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Phone'" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Phone' ) this.value=''" />
        <textarea id="text" name="text" value="Message"
                    onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message'}" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value=='Message') this.value=''}" />  
        <input type="reset" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>  
</form>
```

Comment: And the error I got was pretty bad one. It was really difficult to track down, so this is what I did that works. Since I'm using WAMP, I had to modify it's php.ini file, so I changed the *sendmail_from* to one of the e-mail addresses I have on my hMailServer. I dunno why it works, but it does. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Unless my lack of coffee is playing tricks on my eyes, you have not specified a name attribute on those inputs. $_POST does not contain the ID of the element, but rather the 'name' and 'value' attributes.

e.g:

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="Name" name="name" ...
```

edit: to debug this theory, try outputting the values of the $_POST variables in your PHP file

Comment: oh, I didn't know that, well I've added name= "name" to them

Answer (score 1):

add attribute `name="field_name"` to the input fields. This might fix the issue.